# wpa_cli add network with space in SSID

Tags: bash, sh

I'm trying to use `wpa_cli` to add a network with a SSID that contains a space using a `.sh` bash file:

```
wpa_cli set_network 0 ssid \"SSID 123\"
```

but the `\"` won't help - `wpa_cli` still interprets the space as separator of two arguments.

Comment: Don't \-escape the `"`: `wpa_cli set_network 0 ssid "SSID 123"` should work (the shell will pass the _contents_ of the double-quoted string as a _single_ argument, after removing the enclosing double-quotes. As an aside: If the string to pass is a _literal_, it's better to use single-quotes.

Comment: If for some reason that doesn't work, you can temporarily disable word-splitting on space by setting `IFS=$'\n'`. (the default is `space tab newline` (in that order).  After attempting `wpa_cli` with the temp `IFS`, reset the original `IFS=$' \t\n'`

Comment: thanks for the input - that was easy ! Thanks a lot :) What turned out working was `wpa_cli set_network 0 ssid \""SSID 123"\"` (in my case the SSID is stored in a variable $SSID. Would you mind to post your comment as answer?

Comment: @Ben: Do you really need _embedded_ quotes in your argument? In your revised example, `wpa_cli` would see the following: `"SSID 123"` - _including_ the double-quotes.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: That would still make the value subject to _globbing_ (not an issue here, but worth noting in general). There's no reason not to use proper quoting.

Comment: Good catch. I've never had issue with `wpa_cli` handling essid's, Your first suggestion is the way I've always done it. (although I generally manually call `wpa_passphrase`)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you mixed escaping quotes with escaping space.

if you have a space in argument (file name or ssid) you can escape space in two ways:

1. using " " or ' '

   ```
   cp "file with spaces" "path with spaces/sub dir"
   cp 'file with spaces' 'path with spaces/sub dir'
   ```

   look out there's a difference between `" "` and `' '`.
    If you use `' '` variable will not be expanded.
2. escaping space with backslash (`\` ).

   ```
   cp file\ with\ spaces path\ with\ spaces/sub\ dir
   ```